# What is the meaning of the statement $2<x<10$?

Tags: functions, continuity

What is the meaning of the statement $$2<x<10$$

[image]

thanks in advance !

Comment: The circled statement tells you that the value of the function is $ax+b$ for those particular values of $x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x$ is greater than $2$ and less than $10$.

Comment: Thanks for the quick Reply !